# Is there a Angular 2 GUI Builder?

Tags: angular, wysiwyg, gui-builder

I researching tools for user interfaces development using Angular 2, but not was able to find one.

Anyone knows if there's a wysiwyg tool to build Angular 2 user interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

No, since Angular stills in RC.